How to calculate the tail probability for multivariate normal distribution
Univariate Case: if $\sqrt{n}(\hat\mu-\mu)\overset{d}{\to}N(0,\sigma^2)$, then the tail probability can be approximated by
$$P\left(\hat{\mu}-\mu\ge t\right)\asymp e^{-nI(t)},$$
where $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $I(t)=\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}$. This can be derived directly or deduced from Cramer's large deviation theorem.
My question is that, for the multivariate case, suppose that
$$\sqrt{n}(\hat\mu-\mu)\overset{d}{\to}N(0,\Sigma),$$
where $\Sigma$ is a matrix. Can we still approximate the tail probability
$P\left(\|\hat{\mu}-\mu\|\ge t\right)$ by an exponential function with an accurate $I(t)$?

see this answer on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/351523/gaussian-concentration-inequality
